# Linear algebra gram-schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

Will the reordering of the original basis before starting the Gram-Schmidt process lead to the same orthogonal basis? Is there an obvious proof for this one or is this clear already?

Comment: I have read that the choice of the first vector will not matter as long as you make the other vectors orthogonal to the chosen vector. But i'm not sure if the resulting set is the same..

Comment: Reordering will, in general, change your resulting basis.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first vector of the original basis will be the first vector of the new basis (possibly normalised), reordering the original basis will change the first vector of the new basis. So it is easy to see that it will change.
Informally, Gram-Schmidt's algorithm chooses a first vector and then constructs an orthogonal basis around that vector. So it depends on which one you start with.